Index notation question. $\vec{\nabla}\times (\vec{\Omega}\times\vec{u})$
I have a silly doubt about index notation. I have, for example $\vec{\nabla}\times (\vec{\Omega}\times\vec{u})$, and I want to write its ith component, which is of course
$$\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_{j}(\epsilon_{klm}\Omega_l u_m)$$
Further simplification leads to
$$\partial_{m}(\Omega_i u_m) - \partial_l (\Omega_l u_i)$$
Let´s take the first term, for example. Do I have to apply the chain rule to get $u_m\partial_m \Omega_i + \Omega_i \partial_m u_m$ or I can just say $\partial_{m}(\Omega_i u_m) = \partial_{m}(u_m \Omega_i)$ which equals to only $(\vec{\nabla}. \vec{u})\vec{\Omega}$ ? I mean the derivative acts in the whole parenthesys right?

What are $\Omega$ and $u$?

Well it´s a Physics problem. $\vec{\Omega}$ is the anguar velocity in the frame where there´s a fluid with velocity field $\vec{u}$. They are all 3-component ordinary vectors.

While this may have come from a physics problem you have not presented it as such. If these are just ordinary vectors then your expression is zero, so these are vector fields?

Yes, these are all coordinate-dependent vector fields. I meant that, sorry.

Ok, first why do you think we should apply chain rule here? Secondly are you summing repeated indices?

Yes, repeated indices are being summed (Einstein notation). I guess I have to apply chain rule because $\partial_{m}$ is acting on $(\Omega_{i} u_{m})$... so I guess the correct form is $u_m \partial_{m} \Omega_{i}+\Omega_{i}\partial_m u_m$

You do not apply chain rule here you apply the product rule to get that:
\begin{align}
[\nabla\times(\Omega\times u)]_i=&\partial_m\left(\Omega_iu_m\right)-\partial_l(\Omega_lu_i)\\
=&u_m(\partial_m\Omega_i)+\Omega_i\partial_mu_m-(\partial_l\Omega_l)u_i-\Omega_l(\partial_lu_m)
\end{align}
Now, note that that $\partial_mu_m=\nabla\cdot u$,and similarly for $\Omega$. Moreover, note that $u_m(\partial_m\Omega_i)=((u\cdot \nabla)\Omega)_i$ and similarly for the other term, hence:
\begin{align}
[\nabla\times(\Omega\times u)]_i=&(u\cdot \nabla)\Omega_i+(\nabla\cdot u)\Omega_i-(\nabla\cdot \Omega)u_i-(\Omega\cdot \nabla)u_i
\end{align}

Thank you. This was super helpful.
